# Run all Django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have this project structure

[image: Structure]

when I run

```
python manage.py test --settings=backend.settings.bitbucket
```

Only tests in `backend/core/tests` are run.

When I run

```
python manage.py test backend.apps.sar --settings=backend.settings.bitbucket
```

or move the files to `backend/core/tests`, everything works fine...
How can I run all the tests at once?

Comment: You may need `__init__.py` in your "apps" and "sar" directories, it's the only difference I can see

Comment: Omg you are right... thanks Sir!